# Boost Voltage before Regulating or vice versa

Tags: power, voltage-regulator, boost, efficiency

I have an input voltage from a 3S battery from 7.4V to 11.1V and I need to regulate / boost it to 5V and 12V. So what is more efficient or what is used in industry

- Regulate the voltage to 5V with e.g. a LM7805 and then boost it from 5V to 12V with an [LM2731](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2731.pdf)
- Boost the voltage to 12V with the LM2731 and then regulate it to 5V with a LM7805

Answer (score 2):

It's probably best to use two circuits in parallel.

One regulates down from the input to 5 V.

The other boosts up from the input to 12 V.

If you use them cascaded like you propose, the power of one of your loads is subject to inefficiency effects from both regulators.

Also consider that using a linear regulator to get from ~10 V input to 5 V output is only about 50% efficient and the regulator is likely to need a heat sink if the load is more than a few 10's of milliamps. A buck switching regulator could be 90% efficient.

Comment: I second this, the most efficient (not necessarily cheapest in terms of component cost) would be to run a buck regulator down to 5V and a boost to 12V.